# Search for pattern and print next lines in pattern matching line

Tags: awk

I have a input file with data

```
cell1
input a;
input a2;
input b;
output z;
cell2 
input a1;
input a2;
output zn;
cell3 
input a1;
input a2;
input b1;
output z;
```

I want my output data as below

```
cell1(a,a2,b,z);
input a;
input a2;
input b;
output z;
cell2 (a1,a2,zn);
input a1;
input a2;
output zn;
cell3 (a1,a2,b1,z);
input a1;
input a2;
input b1;
output z;
```

I started with below idea i.e to Start with searching for cell and if cell found print $2 of next lines in () after cell in that cell, till next cell occurred and loop over it.
But I am getting problem in executing it.

I tried code

```
awk ' /cell/{if (NR >1) print cell , line; cell = 0;line =0} { line= $4} END { print cell, line }' file
```

When I execute this code I am only getting

```
cell1 0
cell2 0
```

Comment: This question has initial data in different format i.e input its data in next line and so on. In this question I just want to print all data present inside a cell in bracket

Comment: I tried the code ```awk ' /cell/{if (NR >1) print cell , line; cell = 0;line =0} { line= $4} END { print cell, line }' file``` but getting ```cell1 0
cell2 0```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file backwards, with some help from `tac` and this `awk` script.

```bsh
tac file | awk '
    /^cell/ {print $0 "(" args ");"; args = ""; next}
    {print; gsub(";","",$2); args = (args ? $2 "," args : $2)}
' | tac
```

Testing with your sample input is giving this output.

```
cell1(a,a2,b,z);
input a;
input a2;
input b;
output z;
cell2 (a1,a2,zn);
input a1;
input a2;
output zn;
cell3 (a1,a2,b1,z);
input a1;
input a2;
input b1;
output z;
```

Comment: Thanks for tac concept. It worked.